# PDF manual download from a Shiny app

Tags: pdf, download, shiny

I have a shiny app and I would like to provide for the users a quick PDF manual of how to use the app that I build. I have tried to do this using the `download button`, but I only get many errors messages. Anyone could help me?
Thanks!

Comment: If it's a static file, probably just add an `tags$iframe` with `src=file_path.pdf`, or just use a URL

Answer (score 0):

I usually put something like:

```
helpText(a("USER MANUAL", href="http://where_the_file_is/the_file.pdf", target="_blank"))
```

in the `ui.R` file.